# How to make a hole in Unity UI?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make a reusable tutorial system for my games. My idea is to use a semi-transparent black panel to block every thing including clicks, but cut a hole on it (with a customized transform e.g. a button on other layers that you want to guide the player to click) to reveal what's behind the hole, and also users' clicks can go through the whole to interact with whatever behind the hole only.

I've been searching for many hours on the internet but still can't find a solution. So what is the proper way to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with masking for the visual part, and Canvas Groups for the interaction part.

---

For the visual part, see [Unity's official UI Mask tutorial](https://youtu.be/g3gpXmo8zRo).

---

As for the interaction part, I am not completely sure this works, as I haven't done it myself, but according to the Unity documentation, you should be able to do it with [Canvas Groups](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CanvasGroup.html).

Have a parent canvas group with the `Block Raycasts` flag set to true (marked), and then, for the non-blocking area use a second canvas group with the `Block Raycasts` flag set to false (unmarked), and the `Ignore Parent Groups` flag set to true (marked). The second group should thus override the parent group's blocking behaviour.

Comment: Thank you. I did managed to make the visual part working successfully using something like this https://answers.unity.com/questions/1066291/invertreverse-ui-mask.html, however the canvas group idea is not working, because the raycasts on the whole screen including the area where we want it to be a hole still will be blocked by the marked image in your example.